# What is the best way to store a nested Json data generated from API into SQL DB using Python

Tags: python, sql, json, python-3.x, api

I have a Json response coming from the API, i need to store this into a SQL DB from python. Apparently the Json data is nested.
What is the best way to store this?

Is there a way i can create table automatically with the schema that is generating by Json response, like it needs to take columns names from Json response and needs to be quite dynamic that if in future if there is a new value coming in it needs to create a new column

Here is the Json data example -

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 111,
      "name": "Test",
      "client": {
        "id": 12,
        "name": "Test"
      },
      "office": {
        "id": 12,
        "name": "Test",
        "country": "Test"
      },
      "primaryContact": {
        "name": "<PrimaryContactName>",
        "email": "<PrimaryContactEmail>"
      },
      "data": [
        {
          "fieldid": 10,
          "fieldLabel": "Test1",
          "hasMutlipleValues": false,
          "multiValues": [],
          "fieldValue": "Test2",
          "sfid": 0
        },
        {
          "fieldid": 132,
          "fieldLabel": "Test3",
          "hasMutlipleValues": false,
          "multiValues": [],
          "fieldValue": "Test4"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "total": 1
}
```

Comment: Why can't you save it like a string in DB and fetch it and manipulate when required.If somehow you keep on generating the tables based out of JSON , then just think a case, where Json is quite large with so many entities.

Comment: It really depends on what you want to do with the retrieved data—do you need to retrieve it for display? Are you going to be querying it based on some of the fields?

Comment: Well, i get that, even i felt storing as string would be a potential option.
But now assuming that it is not dynamic, Any thoughts on what would be the better way of parsing this and storing.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way would be to store the json itself in db. Since you mentioned the JSON is dynamic in nature.

This is with mariadb.

```
CREATE TABLE Sample (id int, json_file JSON, PRIMARY KEY(id));
```

If the above method doesn't work you can convert the json to string and then store in db in a VARCHAR field .

```
import json
json_string = json.dump(json_file)
```

Creating columns as they are generated is something I feel is unnecessary.